# Hiding fields and removing them from a check function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few input textfields on a screen and some hide at certain time. I am trying to disable them when they are `hide()`.

I have tried `.prop` and `.attr`  to disable, but during the check it is still treating them like they are there.
Any suggestions?

So on my button function I have this variable that checks all the boxes to see if nothing is in it

```
var emptyTextBoxes = $('input:text').filter(function () {
    return this.value === "";
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `is()` with the `:hidden` selector for this:

```
var emptyTextBoxes = $('input:text').filter(function () {
    return !$(this).is(':hidden') && this.value === "";
});
```

Or `:not`:

```
var emptyTextBoxes = $('input:text:not(:hidden)').filter(function () {
    return this.value === "";
});
```

Comment: Are you saying to set up another variable that pertains to that particular input field? $('gp1: text')

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You don't need any further variables. The changes I made above were to the condition in the `filter` or the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.is()`

```
var emptyTextBoxes = $('input:text').filter(function () {
    return !$(this).is(':hidden') && this.value === "";
});
```

Comment: Why bother to post this answer when it's exactly the same as mine?